# About Menu Child's Slide Toggle jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a menu for mobile version, and I face some problems with my script.
This is my code of menu `slideToggle();` function :

```
$('.menu ul li').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu ul li ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uikithemes/o1g83hbc/) demo.

When I click on menu parent, all child's will appear, for example : I want to appear only the child's of the menu parent(1) clicked, and I want something like radio button when I click on another parent(2) the childs of parent(1) disappear and the childs of parent(2) appear.
That's it, thanks!

> Note : Resize the window of result section to see the mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g83hbc/4/)

Js:

```
$('.menu ul li').on('click', function(){
    $(".menu ul li").not(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi again, I face some problems here, when I browse my template on my Galaxy the slideToggle menu not working!! maybe because I use css3 transform, but how I can resolve this problem? this is my template http://neone-theme.blogspot.com/ please can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I use Asus Zenfone5 and your template works fine on chrome in my phone. You are using which model of galaxy and which browser(native or chrome or anyother)

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime and I use the default Browser.